# List of all inbuilt Wordpress shortcodes

Tags: shortcode

I am newbie in wordpress but not very new.

When I came to know that wordpress have inbuilt shortcodes like audio, video, gallery, playlist.

I have searched for a list of inbuilt shortcodes that WordPress provides but I did not get anything except above can anybody provide me a link which has a list of inbuilt wp shortcodes.

And

one more thing if WordPress provide more inbuilt shortcodes are they only work in wordpress.com

I know that you guys may thing I am a fool or idiot but I want to know.

Comment: https://en.support.wordpress.com/shortcodes/ Shortcodes will work fine for both wordpress.com and self-hosted, as long as whatever is creating them is installed.

Comment: @hwl, actually no, wordpress.com is not wordpress the software and you should never assume it works the same

Comment: @MarkKaplun Point taken

Comment: Check this official support page from wordpress
[Shortcodes-Support-wordpress.com](https://en.support.wordpress.com/shortcodes/)
It lists all the codes along with their description and instructions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can actually list all of the available shortcodes for your WordPress installation by using the following code:

```
<?php
global $shortcode_tags;
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($shortcode_tags); 
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

It will show the main WordPress shortcodes plus any shortcodes for installed plugins which can be handy too!

Answer (score 3):

You got almost all of them:

```
caption
gallery
audio
video
playlist
embed
```

You can see their associated functions in [`wp-includes/media.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/media.php) and [`wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php).

I don't know if there's a list somewhere, I just searched WordPress source code for `add_shortcode`.